# Unable to enable PHP gd extension in AWS Ubruntu

Tags: php, gd

I am trying to use Intervention/Image package for a Laravel 9 Project. I used the following command

```
$image =  Image::make($request->file('file'))->resize(300, 200);
```

And it displayed an error message: **GD Library extension not available with this PHP installation.**

So I used the following command to install gd

```
 sudo apt-get install php-gd
```

And it installed the package. The command **apt-cache search libgd** also displays some output

```
gir1.2-gdata-0.0 - GObject introspection data for the GData webservices library
libgd-dev - GD Graphics Library (development version)
libgd-graph-perl - Graph Plotting Module for Perl 5
libgd-perl - Perl module wrapper for libgd
libgd-text-perl - Text utilities for use with GD
libgd3 - GD Graphics Library
```

I have also uncommented **;extension gd** in /etc/php/8.0/fpm/php.ini

```
extension=gd
```

I have also restarted the server. Still, the gd extension is not enabled. The following command displays no output.

```
php -i | grep 'GD'
```

And when I extension_loaded(), it returns false

```
>>> extension_loaded('gd')
=> false

>>> extension_loaded('pdo')
=> true

>>> extension_loaded('mbstring')
=> true
```

Is there anything else I need to do to enable the gd extension?

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled the gd extension using the following command:

```
sudo apt install php8.0-gd
```

After this the **gd** extension is enabled.